# Storing objects for locating by x,y coordinates

Tags: java, tree, spatial, quadtree

I'm trying to determine a fast way of storing a set of objects, each of which have an x and y coordinate value, such that I can quickly retrieve all objects within a certain rectangle or circle.
For small sets of objects (~100) the naive approach of simply storing them in a list, and iterating through it, is relatively quick.  However, for much larger groups, that is expectedly slow.
I've tried storing them in a pair of TreeMaps as well, one sorted on the x coordinate, and one sorted on the y coordinate, using this code:

```
xSubset = objectsByX.subSet( minX, maxX );
ySubset = objectsByY.subSet( minY, maxY );
result.addAll( xSubset );
result.retainAll( ySubset );
```

This also works, and is faster for larger sets of objects, but is still slower than I would like.
Part of the problem is also that these objects move around, and need to be inserted back into this storage, which means removing them from and re-adding them to the trees/lists.
I can't help but think there must be better solutions out there.
I'm implementing this in Java, if it makes any difference, though I expect any solution will be more in the form of a useful pattern/algorithm.

Answer (score 14):

[Quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) seem to solve the specific problem I asked.  [Kd-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) are a more general form, for any number of dimensions, rather than just two.

[R-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) may also be useful if the objects being stored have a bounding rectangle, rather than being just a simple point.

The general term for these type of structures is [Spatial Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index).

There is a Java implementation of [Quadtree](http://openmap.bbn.com/doc/api/com/bbn/openmap/util/quadtree/QuadTree.html) and [R-Tree](http://jsi.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4):

The general term is a [Spatial Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index). I guess you should choose according to the [existing implementations](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/implement/quadtree/implement.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

[A quadtree](http://openmap.bbn.com/doc/api/com/bbn/openmap/util/quadtree/QuadTree.html) is the [structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) which is usually used for that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Kd-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree).

Answer (score 1):

Simple QuadTree implementation in C# (easy to translate into java)
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/QuadTree.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the x cords in a map, and the y cords in another map, and have the map values point to the object.

```
        TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, Point>> xMap = new TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, Point>>();
        for (int x = 1; x < 100; x += 2)
            for (int y = 0; y < 100; y += 2)
                {
                    Point p = new Point(x, y);
                    TreeMap<Integer, Point> tempx = xMap.get(x);
                    if (tempx == null)
                        {
                            tempx = new TreeMap<Integer, Point>();
                            xMap.put(x, tempx);
                        }
                    tempx.put(y, p);
                }
        SortedMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, Point>> tempq = xMap.subMap(5, 8);
        Collection<Point> result = new HashSet<Point>();
        for (TreeMap<Integer, Point> smaller : tempq.values())
            {
                SortedMap<Integer, Point> smallerYet = smaller.subMap(6, 12);
                result.addAll(smallerYet.values());
            }
        for (Point q : result)
            {
                System.out.println(q);
            }
    }
```

Comment: If you're dealing with points on a contiguous plane instead of a few discrete points, you could improve this by using "buckets" of a particular size.  Not as good as a quad tree, but simpler to implement.