# Fastest way of finding object in collection with coordinates near point

Tags: algorithm, search, performance, spatial

I have collection of objects. Each object represents a coordinate range (ie, a block). What I want is to find the object near another coordinate in a given direction.

Is there a way to do this without traversing the whole collection all the time?

Comment: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132319/storing-objects-for-locating-by-xy-coordinates#132393).

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132319/storing-objects-for-locating-by-xy-coordinates#132393.  Any reason to keep this version open?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [Binary Space Partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning), and similar algorithms ([Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) comes to mind, along with variations on [Plane Sweet Algorithms](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~cs251/ClosestPair/ClosestPairPS.html))

Answer (score 0):

While inserting the objects .. sort them by the cordinates then use divide and conquer algorithm to search for your nearest possibility