# Java algorithm for find intersection between intervals

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a time interval like this:

```
[5,10]
```

and I have more list of time point, with different length, for example:

```
t1=[3,6,9,10] 
t2=[2,4,5,6,10]
..
```

where in `t1 [3,6]` is the first interval, `[6,9]` the second and so on.

Same thing for `t2` and other list.

Now I need to save the list, and the specific interval, that intersect with first time interval. For example in `t1` I have `[3,6]` that intersect on `[5,10], [6,9]` that intersect with `[5,10]`, etc.

I have made an algorithm but I work with more data and I need a fast algorithm.
For example if I work with 300.000 list and every list have 200 time points my algorithm 1 fine in about 5-10sec. But if I have 10.000 or more time point the algorithm is very slow.

My algorithm is like this:

```
First time interval <- [t1,t2]
For each list
  For each time interval [s1,s2] in list
     if(s1>= t1 && s2 <= t2)
     {
         saveIntervall()
     }
     else if (s1<= t2 && s2 > t2)
     {
         saveIntervall()
     }
     else if(s1 <  t1 && s2 >= t1)
     {
        saveIntervall()
     }
     else if (s1 < t1 && s2 > t2)
     {
        saveIntervall()
     }
```

Edit1: Yes I have ordered list.

Edit2: I have another problem, when i find the intersaction i need to calclulate a score between 0 and 1 of how the intersection is large.
I use this:

```
            double score = 0.0d;
        if(s1>= t1 && s2 <= t2)
        {
            score = (s2-s1) / (t2-t1);
        }
        else if(t2 >= s2 && t1 > s1)
        {
            score = (s2-t1) / (t2-t1);
        }
        else if(t2 < s2 && t1 <= s1)
        {
            score = (t2-s1) / (t2-t1);
        }
        else
        {
            score = 1;
        }
```

I can speed up this too?

Comment: Is your lists ordered ? Besides, I think there is already an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303591/a-range-intersection-algorithm-better-than-on

Comment: What does it mean for there to be more than two numbers in these arrays?  `t1` looks to be just a pair of intervals, but I don't see how `t2` maps to intervals at all.

Comment: @dimo414 If I understood the interval is composed by an element and the next element. So the list just has to have at least to values.

Comment: In the "first time intervall" i have make an error and i have only one intervall. In the other list the interval is composed by an element and the next element like Jorge say.

Comment: Is your search list always only 2 elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, your data structure is confusing - if you're trying to talk about discrete intervals of time, structure your data like so; for instance `int[][]` where the inner array is always length 2, so your `t1` becomes:

```
int[][] t1 = {{3,6}, {6,9}, {9,10}};
```

Using the right structure will probably help you simplify your algorithm and make it easier to work with.

---

Better than properly structured arrays, however, would be to use a dedicated type to represent these intervals, such that you could pass around `List<Interval>` objects and do some sort of contains check on them.  But don't reinvent the wheel.  The awesome [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) provides a robust [`Range`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) class that you can use.  Even better though, it also provides [`RangeSet`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html) and [`RangeMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html) classes, which let you easily do the things you're talking about.  See also their [Ranges Explained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained) article which covers the basics.

Note that you could pretty easily transform your current design into `Range` objects internally, if you can't redesign the array structure externally.

Having tried at one point to build my own `IntervalSet` class, let me tell you that it's a tricky problem to get right and you'll save yourself a lot of headaches using their well designed and highly tested range utilities.

Here's the way that I would do what you're describing with Guava - notice that we avoid even needing to *think* about the math involved - `Range` does the right thing for us:

```
/**
 * Given a Range and an group of other Ranges, identify the set of ranges in
 * the group which overlap with the first range.  Note this returns a Set<Range>
 * not a RangeSet, because we don't want to collapse connected ranges together. 
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<?>> Set<Range<T>>
        getIntersectingRanges(Range<T> intersects, Iterable<Range<T>> ranges) {
    ImmutableSet.Builder<Range<T>> builder = ImmutableSet.builder();
    for(Range<T> r : ranges) {
        if(r.isConnected(intersects) && !r.intersection(intersects).isEmpty()) {
            builder.add(r);
        }
    }
    return builder.build();
}

/**
 * Given a 2-length array representing a closed integer range, and an array of
 * discrete instances (each pair of which therefore represents a closed range)
 * return the set of ranges overlapping the first range.
 * Example: the instances array [1,2,3,4] maps to the ranges [1,2],[2,3],[3,4].
 */
public static Set<Range<Integer>> getIntersectingContinuousRanges(int[] intersects,
        int[] instances) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(intersects.length == 2);
    Preconditions.checkArgument(instances.length >= 2);
    ImmutableList.Builder<Range<Integer>> builder = ImmutableList.builder();
    for(int i = 0; i < instances.length-1; i++) {
        builder.add(Range.closed(instances[i], instances[i+1]));
    }
    return getIntersectingRanges(Range.closed(intersects[0], intersects[1]),
                                 builder.build());
}
```

Using your examples:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] interval = {5,10};
    int[] t1 = {3,6,9,10};
    int[] t2 = {2,4,5,6,10};

    System.out.println(getIntersectingContinuousRanges(interval, t1));
    System.out.println(getIntersectingContinuousRanges(interval, t2));
}
```

The above prints out:

> ```
> [[3‥6], [6‥9], [9‥10]]
> [[4‥5], [5‥6], [6‥10]]
> ```

Answer (score 5):

The intersection of two intervals [s1, s2] and [t1, t2] is empty **if and only if**:

```
    t2 < s1 or s2 < t1
```

So for two intervals to check if the two are intersecting or not you need to do only the test above.

Also once you know that s2 < t1 then there is no point to continue further on the list that brought t1 since the larger intervals will never intersect, which means you should move on.

Naive Psuedo Algorithm:

```
   given [s1, s2]
   for each list [t1, t2, ... t(n)] in search_lists
        for each interval [t(x), t(x+1)] from [t1, t2, ... t(n] (x goes from 0 to n-1)
           if t(x+1) < s1
              continue
           if s2 < t(x)
              break
           saveInterval()
```

This can be improved quite a bit to really use the fact that [t1, t2, .. , t(n)] is sorted.

first note that `[s1, s2]` will intersect with `[t(x), t(x+1)]` **iff** `t(x+1) >= s1` and `s2 >= t(x)`

However

```
if t(x) >= s1 then for every h>0      `t(x+h) >= s1`
```

also

```
if s2 >= t(x) then for every h>0  `s2 >= t(x-h)`
```

so if we find the smallest i so that t(i+1)>=s1 then all the intervals from `[t(i), t(i+1)]` on-wards meet the first condition of intersection; i.e. (`[t(i+1), t(i+2)]` , `[t(i+2), t(i+3)]` ...)

and if we find the largest j so that s2 >= t(j-1) then all the intervals from `[t(j-1), t(j)]` backwards meet the second condition . i.e. (`[t(j-2), t(j-1)]`, `[t(j-3), t(j-2)]` ...)

All the intervals between i and j meet both criteria and only them.

So the final algorithm is:

```
given [s1, s2]
for each list [t1, t2, ... t(n)] in search_lists
    find the smallest i such that t(i+1)>=s1  
    find the biggest  j such that s2>= t(j-1)

    if j>i then all the intervals between `{t(i)... t(j)}` intersect with [s1, s2]
    otherwise there is no intersection.
```

Since `{t1, t2, t3...t(n)}` is sorted we can use binary search to find the indices `i` and `j` efficiently

EDIT2:

The intersection of [s1,s2] and [t1, t2] is:
  `[max(s1, t1), min(s2,t2)]`

the sizes are:
`L1 = s2-s1`
`L2 = t2-t1`
`L3 = min(s2,t2) - max(s1,t1)`

The score you are looking for is: `L3/ min(L2, L1)` a score between 0 and 1.

```
(min(s2,t2) - max(s1,t1)) / ( min(s2-s1, t2-t1) )
```

The cost of calculating this is 3 tests, 3 minus operations and one floating point operation.
But I am assuming the intervals are valid and the intersection exists otherwise more tests are needed. (`s2>s2`, `t2>t1` and `min(s2,t2) > max(s1,t1)`. The final test is the same **iff** condition for intersection from the discussion above.

Comment: in an ordered list, he could also ommit the `t2<s1` check. in words: "if next interval starts before this one ends: Match"

Answer (score 0):

Given left boundary and length of two intervals, intersection can be testedby the following code.

```
protected boolean intervalOverlap( int pos1, int length1, int pos2, int length2 ){
  int pos_A_left  = pos1;
  int pos_A_right = pos1 + length1;
  int pos_B_left  = pos2;
  int pos_B_right = pos2 + length2;
  return pos_B_left < pos_A_right && pos_A_left < pos_B_right;
}
```

There is a short [article](http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/checking-for-interval-overlap/) in which this approach is discussed. Furthermore, an alternative representation of intervals (using center and length) is presented, for which intersection test can be implemented more efficiently.