# Efficient/scalable Python algorithm for finding the intersection of multiple lists of tuples?

Tags: python, algorithm, set, tuples, intersection

I have multiple lists containing tuples, e.g.,

```
list_A = [(start_1, end_1), (start_2, end_2), (start_3, end_3)]
list_B = [(start_4, end_4), ...]
```

Is there a smart way to go about generating a `result_list` that contains only the intersections, without having to search through each list in a nested fashion O(n^m)?

Example:

```
list_A = [('8:00 AM', '10:00 AM'), ('12:59 PM', '3:00 PM'), ('5:04 PM', '7:23 PM')]
list_B = [('9:06 AM', '9:47 AM'), ('9:51 AM', '12:45 PM'), ('1:33 PM', '2:52 PM'), ...]
list_C = [...]
list_D = [...]
# etc. etc. (m lists)
```

Please see the image below for an illustration of the problem:
[image: Intersection Problem]

Comment: Can you provide an *example*? are you dealing with integers? floats? what is the nature of you data??

Comment: maybe you could do the same as your drawing does: create a 2D array (e.g. list of lists) with the tuples drawn out, and then check from the array the vertical columns the same way as we can do from the image visually?

Comment: are you looking for the start and end inclusive ? or only start inclusive?

Comment: @BinyaminEven they're times - sorry for not including an example

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303591/a-range-intersection-algorithm-better-than-on

Comment: @antont sounds like that might work, but my x axis is continuous, which makes discretization a tricky part of it

Comment: @AkshaySehgal they're timestamps, so I believe they should both be inclusive i.e., I would probably use `>=` and `<= ` for everything

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in O(m*n) -

```
r = [[1,3], [5,7], [9,11]]
s = [[2,4], [5,6], [7,9], [11,14]]

r = [[i[0],i[1]+1] for i in r] #to make it inclusive at ends
s = [[i[0],i[1]+1] for i in s] #to make it inclusive at ends

overlapping_ranges = [set(range(*i[0])).intersection(set(range(*i[1]))) for i in list(itertools.product(r, s))]
overlapping_ranges = [i for i in overlapping_ranges if i] #removing nullsets
```

```
[{2, 3}, {5, 6}, {7}, {9}, {11}]
```