# Find all points in a radius of one point (Python)

Tags: python, performance, 2d, point

I have two datasets with a number of points. Both datasets have points with gps coordinates.
the point are located in the same area.

I have to find for one point out of dataset A, all points from dataset B, which are in a radius of point from dataset A.

I can do it like an idiot and do it with to for loops, but it takes to much time for big datasets.

Can you give me hints for algorithm, which can help me to find the solution with best performance?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121628/finding-all-points-in-certain-radius-of-another-point

Answer (score 1):

If you are currently using basic loops to perform your calculations, it is likely you can get much improved performance without changing your algorithm, just through restructuring how you are doing the calculations.

I have run a series of benchmarks to illustrate how different approaches impact performance. For simplicity, I have set up these benchmarks using simple x/y coordinates rather than the Haversine formula or something equivalent, but the same principles apply.

There are two key ideas in the benchmark progression. Firstly, where possible simplify the calculation: the fewer operations the less time it will take. Secondly, move loop calculations into numpy which has a much lower overhead performing vector operations.

The performance of the different approaches:

| Method | Time | Relative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic loop method | 45.039 | 22.68 |
| Checking against r squared removes square root operation | 28.941 | 14.58 |
| Using list comprehension speeds construction of list | 26.190 | 13.19 |
| Using 1d arrays means loops are performed in C vector operations | 1.986 | 1.00 |
| Using 2d numpy arrays can help with memory locality, but not in this case | 3.452 | 1.74 |

These results come from the following test code:

```py
import numpy as np
import random
import timeit

random.seed(1)

count_a = 10000000
r = 2.5
r_squared = r * r

a_tuples = [(random.uniform(0, 10), random.uniform(0, 10)) for _ in range(count_a)]
b = (random.uniform(4, 8), random.uniform(4, 8))

# tuple of 1d numpy arrays
a_arrs = (np.array([v[0] for v in a_tuples]), np.array([v[1] for v in a_tuples]))

# 2d numpy arrays
a_2d = np.array(a_tuples)
b_arr = np.array(b)

def method0():
    """Basic loop method"""
    out = []
    for x, y in a_tuples:
        dx = x - b[0]
        dy = y - b[1]
        distance = ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy)) ** .5
        if distance <= r:
            out.append((x, y))
    return out

def method1():
    """Checking against r squared removes square root operation"""
    out = []
    for x, y in a_tuples:
        dx = x - b[0]
        dy = y - b[1]
        if ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy)) <= r_squared:
            out.append((x, y))
    return out

def method2():
    """Using list comprehension speeds construction of list"""
    return [(x, y) for x, y in a_tuples if (((dx := x - b[0]) * dx) + ((dy := y - b[1]) * dy)) <= r_squared]

def method3():
    """Using 1d arrays means loops are performed in C vector operations"""
    x, y = a_arrs
    dx = x - b[0]
    dy = y - b[1]
    return np.nonzero(((dx * dx) + (dy * dy)) <= r_squared)[0]

def method4():
    """Using 2d numpy arrays can help with memory locality, but not in this case"""
    a_b = a_2d - b
    a_b2 = a_b * a_b
    sum_sq = np.sum(a_b2, axis=1)
    return np.nonzero(sum_sq <= r_squared)[0]

m0 = method0()
assert m0 == method1()
assert m0 == method2()
assert m0 == [(a_arrs[0][i], a_arrs[1][i]) for i in method3()]
assert m0 == [(a_2d[i][0], a_2d[i][1]) for i in method4()]

number = 10
t0, t1, t2, t3 = None, None, None, None
t0 = timeit.timeit(lambda: method0(), number=number)
t1 = timeit.timeit(lambda: method1(), number=number)
t2 = timeit.timeit(lambda: method2(), number=number)
t3 = timeit.timeit(lambda: method3(), number=number)
t4 = timeit.timeit(lambda: method4(), number=number)

tmin = min((t0, t1, t2, t3, t4))

print(f'| Method               | Time     | Relative        |')
print(f'|------------------    |------    |---------------  |')
print(f'| {method0.__doc__}    | {t0:.3f} | {t0 / tmin:.2f} |')
print(f'| {method1.__doc__}    | {t1:.3f} | {t1 / tmin:.2f} |')
print(f'| {method2.__doc__}    | {t2:.3f} | {t2 / tmin:.2f} |')
print(f'| {method3.__doc__}    | {t3:.3f} | {t3 / tmin:.2f} |')
print(f'| {method4.__doc__}    | {t4:.3f} | {t4 / tmin:.2f} |')
```